# Ошибка в Android Studio Duplicate files copied in APK com/sun/syndication/rome.properties

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Сама ошибка:

```
Error:Execution failed for task
':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
copied in APK com/sun/syndication/rome.properties   File1:
C:\Users\Кирилл\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\rome\rome\0.5\4d36835b2d337350f7fbac702a9a90270578e795\rome-0.5.jar
    File2:
C:\Users\Кирилл\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.rome\rome\1.0.0\8b4f0da455c59746435e987285b30c22b09ba18d\rome-1.0.0.jar
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "giftapp.rsstest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'net.java.dev.rome:rome:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.totsp.feedpod:purl-org-content:0.3' }
```

Comment: у вас либа rome-0.5.jar случаем в папке libs не лежит?

Comment: как по мне, у вас сразу 2 версии библиотеки подключены одновременно